# R Language: How to Set ylim?

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot data with maximum 9.70 and minimum -58.9.

I coded:

```
plot(BriannaJan[,3,i], type = "line", col="black", 
     main = "Brianna January Trend", xlab = "days", ylab="Temperature", 
     ylim = -60:10)
```

But I get error:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'ylim' value
```

How can I set ylim? y value range has to be from -60 to 10.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`-60:10` generates a sequence from `-60` to `10`, what you need as the ylim is a min and max value (with syntax `c(min, max)`) instead of a sequence, try this:

```
ylim=c(-60,10)
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to change it to

```
ylim=c(-60,10)
```

so the whole thing would be:

```
plot(BriannaJan[,3,i], type = "line", col="black", main ="Brianna January Trend",
   xlab = "days", ylab="Temperature", ylim=c(-60,10))
```